# How to install angular cli on MacOs Mojave

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've been fighting with getting the angular cli install on my mac. I've read through the docs on Angulars website,  git as well as SO post. I've tried the commands:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and I've tried updating the npm global path using the instructions at [EACCES Permissions on npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

What I am seeing is if I follow the instructions from the npm site I can locate the ng module for the current session. It will load and I can execute ng commands. However as soon as I close the terminal and re-open it, if I type `ng -v or ng --version` I get the `bash ng: command not found`.

Anyone ever run into this? I think I've followed about ever step from SO posts as well as other online forums and I am at a loss as to why the pathing keeps getting lost when I close the terminal. Is there a profile or source I need to reference to make the terminal look to recognize the ng command? Using  `source ~/.profile` apparently isn't working

.profile contains the following entries:

```
export PATH=/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Do I need to manually add reference to the @angular directory here?

Update: I checked to verify if angular was installed using the following:

```
xxxxxxx-MacBook-Pro:bin xxxxxxxx$ npm list -g --depth 0
/Users/xxxxxxxx/.npm-global/lib
├── @angular/cli@7.3.2
├── jshint@2.10.1
└── npm@6.8.0
```

So it is showing as being installed in .npm-global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well apparently it was a permissions issue. This doesn't explain the core question of how to correct the original issue in npm, but using Brew I was able to run the installation and it retained the pathing to ng command.

Maybe this will help others if you have the issue I did, but using brew and the command:

```
brew install angular-cli
```

I'm now able to access ng command through multiple terminal sessions.

Comment: Worked for me. However since I was coming from having angular-cli 6 installed globally, I also had to do: rm '/usr/local/bin/ng' && brew link --overwrite angular-cli

Answer (score -1):

Try

npm install -g @angular/cli --save

(appending --save) and see if that helps...

Edit:  Try "**sudo** npm install...."

Comment: tried the --save command. Still getting -bash: ng: command not found once installation runs. Verified the install is going to .npm-global directory